How to have different versions of PHP syntax coexist?
In my PHP file this line of code:
private const string NS_HTML = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';

only works for PHP 8.3 or after.
If I want to make my library compatible to 8.2, is downgrading the syntax the only way to go? i.e.
private const NS_HTML = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';

What I really want to achieve is some sort of magic like:
if (PHP_VERSION >= '8.3') {
  private const string NS_HTML = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
} else {
  private const NS_HTML = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
}

You may argue dropping the type constraint from a constant is not a big deal, but I am just giving out a simple example. Another 8.3 feature I use is the #[Override] attribute and I would love to keep them.
Update: based on answer from How can I code for multiple versions of PHP in the same file without error?:
This would work:
if (\PHP_VERSION_ID >= 803000) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/class-a-php8.3.php';
} else {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/class-a-php8.2.php';
}

While this won't:
if (\PHP_VERSION_ID >= 803000) :
    class A {
        private const string NS_HTML = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
        ...
    }
else:
    class A {
        private const NS_HTML = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
        ...
    }
endif;

i.e. different versions of syntax must sit in separate files.

Thanks @Mureinik I've updated my question

How does your update reflect advice from the other question - none of the answers would suggest this approach would work.

"If I want to make my library compatible to 8.2, is downgrading the syntax the only way to go" - yeah, why not? Is there anybody forcing you to write your code such that it is only compatible with 8.3? On the other hand, if you really want to use all new features, why not drop compatibility with 8.2 in your library?

@NigelRen You're right. I explored the options further and found that different syntax must sit in separate files!

@NicoHaase No strong reason behind this, I am just curious about if there exists a clean solution to have both wide compatibility and latest feature at the same time. I know I'm being greedy here :-)

Sounds that using difference versions of a library would be a better end user experience.  So versions would have their own set of dependencies - including which version of php is required.

by the way, you can use Rector to automate creation of downgraded version.
